# Haskell list condition

Tags: haskell, filter, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, ambiguous-type-variable

I have started to learn Haskell yesterday, so you can consider me a complete newbie.

I wanted a list of prime numbers, so I stated:

```
multiples max reihe = [ x | x <- [reihe*2,reihe * 3..max], x<= max ]
notPrimes max = [ truncate x | x <- concat [ multiples max reihe | reihe <- [2..(max/2)]]]
primes max = [ x | x <- [2..max] , elem x (notPrimes max) ]
```

The first snippet is a function which returns all multiples of `reihe` not exceeding `max`.

The second is a function which returns all non-primes except *1* up to the specified maximum.

The last snippet does not work, and I don't understand why. If I evaluate `elem x (notPrimes max)` with an arbitrary value of `x` I get an answer, but *this* "filter" throws an error:

```
<interactive>:47:1: error:
* Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `print'
  prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Show Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
    instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
    instance Show Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
    ...plus 23 others
    ...plus 15 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: Note that the primes are those values of `[2..max]` that are *not* elements of `notPrimes max`.

Comment: There is no "print" in the code you have shown. Please show us the whole code, thanks. Do your type signatures (if any) use Int or Integer for the numeric type ?

Comment: Regarding `reihe <- [2..(max/2)]`, you have to remember that in Haskell, operator / is for fractional/real numbers only. You might want to use `div max 2` instead.

Comment: Usually in Haskell it is convenient to start coding by writing a type signature e.g. `foo :: Int -> String -> Bool` before writing the implementation. This makes GHC produce better error messages and avoids using the wrong inferred type by mistake. Also, I'd recommend to keep warnings always turned on with the `-Wall` flag -- many potential mistakes are detected by that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the use of fractional numbers, induced by the `/` operator.

As the function `truncate` converts from *some* `RealFrac` type to *some* `Integral` type, this equation:

```
notPrimes max = [ truncate x | x <- concat [ multiples max reihe | reihe <- [2..(max/2)]]
```

will force argument `max` to be fractional, and the *result* of `notPrimes` to be a list of integral values.

But then, this equation:

```
primes max = [ x | x <- [2..max] , elem x (notPrimes max) ]
```

will force `x` to be fractional like `max` **AND** integral like the elements of `notPrime max`. Remember, Haskell does not do *implicit* type conversions.

So when you try to actually evaluate something like `primes 100`, you force the Haskell interpreter to assign actual types to every thing, and things get ugly.

The key ideas are:

1. do not use fractional numbers in integer problems, unless really necessary
2. use explicit type signatures as appropriate

Besides, as mentioned in a comment, there is a missing logical negation (an additional `not` call).

**A possible integral-only solution:**

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> :type (/)
 (/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
 λ> 
 λ> :type div
 div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
 λ> 
 λ> multiples max reihe = [ x | x <- [reihe*2,reihe * 3..max], x<= max ]
 λ> notPrimes max = [ x | x <- concat [ multiples max reihe | reihe <- [2..(div max 2)]]]
 λ> primes max = [ x | x <- [2..max] , not $ elem x (notPrimes max) ]
 λ> 
 λ> primes (100::Int)
 [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
 λ>
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Although I don't understand, why my truncate-function was not enough. That was the reason, why I have called this function. Could you explain, why the truncate-function did not do the job?

Comment: `truncate` has type `(RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`. The important thing is not so much what `RealFrac` and `Integeral` actually mean, but that the output type cannot be inferred from the input type. As a result, GHCi didn't know how to convert the resulting list into a string to display, because you never specified what type of values were in the list.

Comment: @MichèleS. I have tried to address this in a modified beginning of my answer. You don't need to invite fractional numbers where they are not needed.

Comment: @MichèleS. `truncate` did make the output to be an `Integral` type, e.g. `Integer`, but `/` made the input be a `Fractional` type, like e.g. `Double`. The two constraints can not (usually?) be satisfied by the same type. Every thing in Haskell has a type, one type, and no type (usually?) can be both an  Integral and a Fractional. Using `div` makes it all be `Integral`, and so e.g. `Integer` fits the  bill. Nice approach BTW! :)